# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException even passing the fully qualified name

Tags: java

I have a jar where I have a code like this:

```
Class.forName("com.abc.test.Test")
```

I'm calling the code by passing the necessary jar like this:

```
java -cp abctest.jar:. Main
```

however it errors out saying

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.abc.test.Test
```

I'm passing the fully qualified name and also passing the corresponding jar, but still its not taking it.

Where I'm making mistake

Comment: You can check if that class is there like this: `unzip -l abctest.jar | grep 'Test.class'`

Comment: @tamasrev: Yeah I have done that, its present. Can see in IntelliJ.

Comment: Then !'d try `Main.class.getClassLoader().getParent()` and use the `Class.forName("com.abc.test.Test", true, parentLoader)` invocation. Hopefully the parent loader knows about the classes in the jar file.

Comment: Can you please post code of Test class